# How to select the sencond,third record of each category?

Tags: mysql

I want get the 2nd and 3nd largest of each category? How to do this ? *Sorry my bad English*

I have table tin_tuc like this

```
||id || id_cat ||some information
||1  || 1      ||      
||2  || 1      ||
||3  || 1      ||
||4  || 1      ||
||5  || 2      ||
||6  || 2      || 
||7  || 3      ||
||8  || 3      ||
||9  || 3      ||
```

Now i want to get two record each category that have value large 2nd and 3th(top 3 except largest value).
the out put i want

```
||id || id_cat ||some information
||2  || 1      ||
||3  || 1      ||
||5  || 2      ||
||6  || 2      || 
||8  || 3      ||
||9  || 3      ||
```

Comment: How about this? - `SELECT * FROM tin_tuc s where(...) <=3 AND (...) > 1 order by id desc`

Comment: can you post an example of what you have on a table and what you want to get? it's not clear. For your current SQL query you may want to try with "HAVING", so you don't need that internal query

Comment: if you can explain your question a bit perhaps what is meaning of your fields i might help you

Comment: for cat_id 3, do you want id 7 and 8 or 8 and 9? I think you want 8 and 9 (2nd and 3rd) but i'm not sure

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The following query will return top 2nd and 3rd song based on category from a table:

```
set @num := 0, @category := '';

select
    songID, `categoryId`, hits
    from 
        (
        select songID, categoryid, hits,
              @num := if(@category = `categoryid`, @num + 1, 1) as row_number,
              @category := `categoryid` as dummy
          from songs
          where categoryid is not null
          order by `categoryid`, hits desc
        ) as temptable

    where temptable.row_number=3 or temptable.row_number=2;
```

here i am sorting all records by category and hits(my priority for example you can select your highest point holding field) in sub-query and then giving each record an incrementing number starting from 1 and resetting when category changes then finally i select 2nd and 3rd record in outer query.

Comment: I think you knew my mind . But when i try this code . I have some errors. I have tried to fix my solution .

Comment: sorry it run but not return any value

Comment: try executing it on mysql console or if you are php user try executing on phpmyadmin there you should atleast find your error perhaps you are changing some fields you shouldn't because here `@num` and `@category` are variables they don not depend on your table

Comment: i use on phpmyadmin and it returnded empty . But when i change where temptable.row_number=3 and temptable.row_number=2 to temptable.row_number<=2 .It run normal(but it return 2 largest value).

Comment: Oh i am so sorry use `or` between both conditions instead of `and` and it should work then.

Comment: you too enjoy you weekend.

Comment: sorry but i don't get correct result (many items in each category)